# Deriving the conditional expectation for a permutation-symmetric measurable function

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Could you help me to understand whether and where I need assumption (2) to assert the following result:

> Consider the real-valued random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ all defined on
>   the same probability space such that:
>
> (1) $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independently distributed
>
> (2) $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are identically distributed
>
> (3) $T:=T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a permutation-symmetric measurable function
>
> Then
>
> $E(T\mid X_i=a)=E(T(X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_i,X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n)\mid X_i=a) \underbrace{=}_{(1)}E(T(X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1}, a, X_{i+1}, \ldots, X_n)) \underbrace{=}_{(3)} E(T(a,X_2,\ldots,X_n))$

In case you conclude that (2) is not required, could you clarify why it seems necessary in van der vaart "Asymptotic Statistics" p. 157 in the last paragraph before section 11.4 ([here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ocg2AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT314&lpg=PT314&dq=permutation-symmetric%20measurable%20function%20van%20der%20vaart&source=bl&ots=Rm4Tw5KK-F&sig=7tl8eZcnYZvwzQVIszwllgxIwlI&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFwtbZ-JrKAhWJfRoKHXc-DJkQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=permutation-symmetric%20measurable%20function%20van%20der%20vaart&f=false) "Consider the special case..." )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without assumption (2) your last step is wrong. With (1) and (3) you can only get to the equation $$E[T \mid X_i = a] = E[T(a, X_2, \ldots, X_{i - 1}, X_1, X_{i + 1}, \ldots, X_n)].$$

Comment: Could you give more details? I don't understand why $X_i \sim X_j$ helps to show above

Comment: Assumptions (1) and (2) let you replace $X_1$ with $X_i$ in my last term. More precisely, these assumptions guarantee $(X_2, \ldots, X_{i - 1}, X_1, X_{i + 1}, \ldots, X_n) \stackrel{d}{=} (X_2, \ldots, X_n)$, which makes the replacement possible.

Comment: Ok, perfect, thanks